# JQuery Autocomplete sorting by ID instead of label/value

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using 1.10.4 Autocomplete, and I've noticed this strange issue where the JSON I'm sending in is in the sorted order I want (alphabetically by value/label). But when the widget displays the listed Autocomplete values, it's displayed in out of order--by ID instead of the label/value like what I had sent in.

I've even tried modifying the success function in my own JS file to try and reorder the JSON, but with no success. So it looks like it's done through the actual Autocomplete JS file

Is there a workaround to this?

EDIT: Is this a browser issue or is this supposed to be browser agnostic? I found that it orders it the way it's sent (alphabetically) in Firefox, but in IE it orders it via ID.

Comment: have you any jsFiddle to show what you tried ?

Comment: I don't yet, but I can whip one up later in a couple of hours or so. Also I'm wondering if this is a browser issue. This seems to be ordering alphabetically in Firefox, but in IE it's ordering by ID.